# Why was my 'statistics' based question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

One of my questions:
[How is UEFI pronounced?](https://superuser.com/questions/817622/how-is-uefi-pronounced?noredirect=1#comment1070936_817622) was closed because it apparently was primarily opinion based. Know that it had the potential to flagged as such, I specifically worded it to ask for 'most common' if not accepted pronunciations to gather/survey numerical information on what the computer community's take was. For future reference, why was my 'statistics' based question closed?

Comment: Because it is opinion based

Comment: How many different ways can you pronounce the word `gif`?

Comment: @Mokubai I pronounce `gif` like standard US English pronunciation would pronounce `monunakashimdalumakilekitekipoppedharnawasukivullacusham`. Just FYI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Who defined what is "most common"? For that you'd have to run surveys with a representative sample of people in a representative sample of countries and then ask them how they would pronounce the four-letter word "UEFI". Anything else would be speculation, or personal taste, but in any case there does not appear to be any ground truth here.

There's a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/178174/how-is-zsh-pronounced?noredirect=1) where people just post what they think it right. And [another one](https://superuser.com/questions/625752/how-do-we-pronounce-etc-folder). Both exhibit the typical problems with these kinds of questions—answers like:

> Everyone I know…
>
> Everywhere I have been…
>
> Purely anecdotal, but…
>
> Everyone I know pronounces…
>
> Most people say…
>
> Am I an idiot for saying…

Generally, it's more of a language issue without a definitive answer. Perhaps it could be  reworded to *explicitly* ask whether there is an official pronunciation. That'd be a question that could only have a "yes" answer with a link to a reference (or "no" with a reference). Any other answer would have to be deleted—like they'd do on [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/).